# implementation of std::begin in gcc stl (why two overloads?)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl

In:

C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\range_access.h

there is following implementation of std::begin, there are two functions:

```
  /**
   *  @brief  Return an iterator pointing to the first element of
   *          the container.
   *  @param  __cont  Container.
   */
  template<typename _Container>
    inline auto
    begin(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
    { return __cont.begin(); }

  /**
   *  @brief  Return an iterator pointing to the first element of
   *          the const container.
   *  @param  __cont  Container.
   */
  template<typename _Container>
    inline auto
    begin(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
    { return __cont.begin(); }
```

my question is why the second overload is actually needed?

Here is some test code I used to find whether I have missed something:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/148278372ff8da3b

Comment: First one returns a `Container::iterator`, second one returns `Container::const_iterator`.

Comment: Doesn't your code tell you why it is needed?

Comment: @DeiDei but for that only first overload suffices.

Comment: @juanchopanza it does not - can you write an answer?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. Maybe explain why you think it isn't needed, given the code you posted.

Comment: @juanchopanza because the first version might as well produce `begin(const _Container& __cont)` using function template type deduction.